# Restrict cloud endpoints API access without using OAuth 2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to restrict access to my endpoints API without using the User object and OAuth 2? I just want to make sure my API can't be accessed from other mobile or web front ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825175/how-do-i-restrict-google-app-engine-endpoints-api-access-to-only-my-android-appl). He creates a unique hash and sends it to the endpoint. It doesn't even need to be that complicated a simple random string password thats sent between the two would work as well.

Comment: After a bit of research I can only conclude. There is no build in way to secure your API. I've found an interesting article describing how it can be done. http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/. It is similar to the way in your link.